# chmod a+x in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-line, chmod

I'm new at Powershell and I need to apply this command to a folder. I've tried lots of results on the internet related to ICACLS but I can't make them work, I've lost the count on how many commands I've tried and none seem to work. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Did you try `icacls.exe "C:\path\to\folder" /grant "everyone:(OI)(CI)(X)"`?

Comment: See `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` commands.

Comment: `a+x` grants All permission to eXecute. Although Windows does technically implement "execute" permission, this is only very rarely used appropriately as a separate permission, as opposed to just granting read permission -- it's more commonly interpreted as traverse permission on folders. It is even less common to apply this as permission for "Everyone", the Windows equivalent of "All". Perhaps you should be more explicit on what it is you're trying to achieve -- specifically, why you think `chmod a+x` is relevant here. Are you trying to port a Linux procedure of some kind?

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, exactly! I was asked to "translate" some commands from Linux to Powershell, in this particular case it was chmod a+x /folder. I tried to search for information and I heard something like this, but nothing was clear enough, since i saw RX flags and "Everyone" alongside /grant (rarely seen, though. And maybe wrong, I've just googled so much that at this point I don't know whats right and what isn't). So, basically "a+x" is useless on Windows? Just giving read permissions is enough?

Comment: It depends on what the procedure is doing. On Linux separate permission is needed to execute things, on Windows it's not. It's quite probable nothing special has to be done at all to make things work -- whatever files are being modified may already be readable by the user(s) that need to read them (through inheriting permissions from their parent folders).